# Python dict to list (math. polynoms)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I got this dictionary which represents mathematical polynomials:

```
{'x1': 2, 'x0': 1, 'x3': 3}
```

I want to convert it to a list (but they can be in random order, or without zero members):

```
{'x1': 2, 'x0': 1, 'x3': 3}
```

to

```
[1,2,0,3]
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the keys into more usable numbers:

```
poly_dict = {int(term[1:]): power for term, power in poly_dict.items()}
```

This assumes that every term starts with `x` so it can just be removed by slicing off the first character, i.e. `term[1:]`.

Then find the maximum power:

```
max_power = max(poly_dict.keys())
```

Initialise a list of powers, defaulting to 0, with a cell for each term:

```
poly_list = [0] * (max_power + 1)
```

Then fill it in:

```
for term, power in poly_dict.items():
    poly_list[term] = power
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the values of the dictionary as list? You can simply archive this with

```
d = {'x1': 2, 'x0': 1, 'x3': 3}
values = list(d.values())
```

So values will be [2, 1, 3]. What do you mean with zero member?

Comment: Zero member is "x2": 0, which is not in the dictionary

Comment: @LukinM26 So this solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[x for x,y in dictionary.items().sort(key=lambda x,y:  int(x[1:]))]`
This converts the dictionary to a list of tuples and sorts the list by the number after the 'x' in the key term. And outputs the values sorted by the keys as such.